# ¿Cómo puedo capturar la posición en una matriz para luego imprimirla?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una matriz 10x10, la lleno con aleatorios, pero cuando imprimo me trae una posicio `10,10`, es como si trajera el final de cada ciclo `for`, este es mi código y les agradezco la ayuda, ya que quiero mejorar en la lógica que es lo mas complicado para mí.

```
int i,j=0,mayor=0;

Console.WriteLine("Matriz de 10*10\n");
int[,] matriz = new int[11, 11];  //Creacion de la matriz de 10*10 (10 filas, 10 columnas)
int[,] matrizposicion = new int[11,11];
Random aleatorio = new Random();
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 10;j++)
    {
        matriz[i,j] = aleatorio.Next(0, 100);
    }

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (matriz[i,j]>mayor)
        {
            mayor = matriz[i, j];
            matrizposicion[i,j] = matriz[i,j];    
        }
        Console.Write(matriz[i, j].ToString()+" ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("El numero mayor es:{0} y esta en la posicion {1},{2}", mayor.ToString(), i.ToString(), j.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Bienvenido Jorge, me imagino que la declaración de las variables `i` y `j` lo haces al inicio, ahora el por qué te sale los valores `i = 10` y `j = 10`, es debido a que en cada iteración del *for* al hacer `i++` o `j++` y al evaluar con `i < 10` o `j < 10` siempre su valor al final va ser 10. Te sugiero que declares 2 variables más y en ellas guardes los valores de `i` y `j` al momento de capturar el mayor.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es que estas mostrando las variables i y j, estas variables tienen el valor de 10 por lo siguiente.
Al hacer

```
for (j = 0; j < 10;j++)
```

Estas iniciando la variable j en 0 y va a terminar cuando no sea menor a 10, al sumarle uno en cada ciclo cuando llegue a 10 la condicion no se va a cumplir y va a salir del for, la variable queda con el valor 10 por eso es lo que te muestra. Lo que deberias hacer no es declarar una nueva matriz para almacenar la posicion, si en cambio dos variables de tipo int donde vas a almacenar las posiciones del numero maximo

Te adjunto el código que hice, están comentados los pasos en el código. Podrías hacer todo en un paso, pero lo dividí en tres para que te sea mas fácil entenderlo

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Creamos la variables
        int[,] matriz = new int[10, 10];
        int numMayor=0, columnaMayor=0, filaMayor=0;
        Random aleatorio = new Random();

        // Asignamos los numeros random a la matriz
        for (int fila = 0; fila < 10; fila++)
        {
            for (int columna = 0; columna < 10; columna++)
            {
                matriz[fila, columna] = aleatorio.Next(0, 100);
            }
        }

        // Mostramos la matriz en pantalla
        for (int fila = 0; fila < 10; fila++)
        {
            for (int columna = 0; columna < 10; columna++)
            {
                Console.Write(matriz[fila, columna] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        // Buscamos el numero mas alto en la matriz y guardamos su valor, fila y columna
        for (int fila = 0; fila < 10; fila++)
        {
            for (int columna = 0; columna < 10; columna++)
            {
                if (matriz[fila, columna] > numMayor)
                {
                    numMayor = matriz[fila, columna];
                    filaMayor = fila;
                    columnaMayor = columna;                       
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("El numero mayor es: {0} y esta en la fila: {1} columna: {2}", numMayor.ToString(), filaMayor.ToString(), columnaMayor.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int posi=0,posj=0,mayor=0;

Console.WriteLine("Matriz de 10*10\n");
int[,] matriz = new int[11, 11];  //Creacion de la matriz de 10*10 (10 
filas, 10 columnas)
Random aleatorio = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10;j++)
    {
        matriz[i,j] = aleatorio.Next(0, 100);
    }

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (matriz[i,j]>mayor)
        {
            mayor = matriz[i, j];
            posi = i;
            posj = j;
        }
        Console.Write(matriz[i, j].ToString()+" ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("El numero mayor es:{0} y esta en la posicion {1},{2}", mayor.ToString(), posi.ToString(), posj.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Varias cosas para anotar :

- debes usar int antes de la variable x y y en cada ciclo for para darle un ámbito local
- No le veo uso a la matriz matrizposicion por lo que puedes eliminar todo lo que la referencie.
- Usa dos variable enteras para alojar la posicion del mayor numero, procura usar nombres descriptivos, en mi caso usé posi y posj (no muy descriptivos :) ).